# Correct way to pass object arrays to functions?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, object

So recently, I have been struggling with passing an array to the function (described below). My problem is that when I pass an array only the first element of the array works properly (shown with cout's). And also, object "Enemy" is a child of "Obj".

Creating an array of enemies:

```
    const int eN = 2;
    Enemy enemyArray[eN];
    for (int i = 0; i <eN; i++) {
        enemyArray[i].creating("abc.png", Type::ENEMY);
        enemyArray[i].position = Vector2f(x, y);
        enemyArray[i].loadChasePoint();
        enemyArray[i].number = i + 100;
        enemyArray[i].updatePosition();
        x += 50; y += 50;
    }
```

The function that includes this array:

```
void Obj::movement(Vector2f mVector, Obj* b, int objsNumber) {
    bool collision = false;
    position.x = position.x + mVector.x;
    for (int i = 0; i < objsNumber; i++) {
        if (!(type == Type::NONE)) {
            //if (type == Type::PLAYER) { cout<<"Inside: "<< b[1].getSprite().getPosition().x << endl;} Prints "0"
            if (isColliding(b[i])) collision = true;
        }
    }
    if (collision == 1) position.x = position.x - mVector.x;
    collision = false;
    position.y = position.y + mVector.y;
    for (int i = 0; i < objsNumber; i++) {
        if (!(type == Type::NONE)) {
            
            if (isColliding(b[i])) collision = true;
        }
    }
    if (collision == 1) position.y = position.y - mVector.y;
}
```

Calling that function:

```
//cout <<"Outside: "<<enemyArray[1].getSprite().getPosition().x<<endl; Prints actuall position
playerArray[0].movement(mVector, enemyArray, eN);
```

Comment: I see nothing wrong in this code regarding the passing of the array and accessing its elements. So what is the ACTUAL problem? Please be more specific.

Comment: On a side note: `if (collision == 1)` should be `if (collision == true)` or just `if (collision)`.  And `if (!(type == Type::NONE))` should be `if (type != Type::NONE)` instead. Also, rather than checking `type` on every loop iteration, since it doesn't change value, you should check it outside of the loop entirely, eg: `if (type != Type::NONE)) { for (int i = 0; i < objsNumber; i++) { if (isColliding(b[i])) collision = true; } }` What is the point of running the same collision loop twice, though? Can't you just merge them into 1 loop, checking `position.x` and `position.y` at the same time?

Comment: You need another level of indirection.  Even assuming `Enemy` is a subclass of `Obj`, an array of `Enemy` is not laid out in memory the same as an array of `Obj`.  The offset needed to find the second `Obj` in an array is not the same as the offset needed to find the second `Enemy` in an array.

Comment: I mean You are kind of right, it should be checked on every loop iteration however, like this: ```for (int i = 0; i < objsNumber; i++) { if (b[i].type != Type::NONE)) { if (isColliding(b[i])) collision = true; } } ```, but this is my bad. 
As I wrote, the problem is that information about the enemy's sprite doesn't pass correctly into function. I can provide the whole code, but it is a little bit large (300 lines).
Another thing, which maybe will be helpful is that I use SFML 2.5.1 and VS 2019.

Comment: @MilesBudnek I think that I understand what you mean. However, could you explain how to do that, or just give a link to some kind of tutorial, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is, that you pass an array of type `Enemy` to a function that expects an array of type `Obj`. That only works if you pass a single object and if `Enemy` inherits from `Obj`. this cannot work for arrays:
`sizeof(Obj)` is some `X`. So accessing `obj[1]` would expect that the second object starts at address `adressof(b)+X`.

But since your object-array is of type `Enemy` that has a different size (most probably X+Y) this pointer arithmetics fails at this point since the real address of the second object would be `adressof(b)+x+y`.

Some variants to solve this:

- make `b` of your `movement` - function a template arguement
- change the `b` argument to a `Obj*`-Array and create pointer array from your enemy list before calling the function

I would prefere the first variant. And if your are going to refactor - I would suggest to get rid of the plain pointers and arrays. use std container instead and use their iterators.